# How to send push notification to Android while application is closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a small application where I receive the message from the **Firabase cloud Messaging** just fine while the app is running our while is on background. I search a lot about this and I could not find a proper answer on how to receive/create notifications in android while the app is closed so please do not think this is a duplicate question. Can someone show me an example about this and how its done?

**This is my Firebase messaging service class**

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String tag = "TAG";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(tag,"FROM"+remoteMessage.getFrom());

        //check if message contains data
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            Log.d(tag,"Message Data" + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        //check if message constains notification
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String body){

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase CLoud Messaging")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }


}
```

**This is my manifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
```

Comment: My workaround was to include notification to the messages i send because if is just FCM message and the application is sleeping, messages get lost, setting message priority to high supposed to work but it doesn't work all the time.

Comment: It would help if you provide an example of your json you are sending via FCM.

Comment: Just a second!!

Comment: I dont think I can see the JSON in FCM

Comment: Are you sending the message manually in the console? Are you sure the message contains data payload? If there is no data payload, the MyFirebaseMessagingService will not get triggered. In console, you would have to fill out the Advanced options section I think.

Comment: Yes I am passing parameters. And yes I am sending the message in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options), there are two types of notifications you can send through FCM.

1. Notification message
2. Data message

The firebase console can only send the first type of message. And the Notification message will be handled by the system if your app is in the backgroud, but it won't work if your app is stopped.

Switch to your own API, and send data messages.

Comment: So what are the changes that I need to make in my code?

Comment: I'm editing my answer to give more insight into the issue.

Comment: Ok but in this case my server side is the Firebase cloud service, and I dont see any option to change the type of message there I think

Comment: You mean the firebase console?

Comment: and I think I am already using the remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())

Comment: My bad, I saw the first line with the `getData()` and my brain bypassed the rest :)

Comment: So for this case, do you know what the problem is? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178207/discussion-between-mauker-and-jose).

Answer (score 1):

So after hours with this problem and with the help of **@Mauker** I finally did it. These are the steps I took and all the information I received from the internet.

First of all forget Firebase Cloud Message to send notifications to your mobile app.
 Second use postman to do those actions.

Notifications are of two types, group notifications where all the people receive the notification at the same time and direct notifications where the notification itself is only for the user to see.

1º If you want group notifications you have to do in you Application launcher class this:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("groupNameChoosenByYou");
```

2º Then you have to create a class to handle this

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String myCustomKey = data.get("title"); //received from postman POST as you can see above
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(myCustomKey)
                .setContentText(myCustomKey+myCustomKey)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

3º Go to postman and do this in your body

**This should be your URL :** https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
{
               "to":"/topics/groupNameChoosenByYou", 
               "data":
               {
                  "title":"Your title",
                  "message":"Your message"
               }
            }
```

4º While in postman and do this in your Headers

```
 Authorization -> Project settings in Firebase -> Cloud Messaging and take the Server key
 Content-type -> application/json
```

5º  If you want to do a **direct notification** for some specific user in the 
`"to":"/topics/groupNameChoosenByYou"`,  replace with the device token id that is generated on the first connection with firebase(when the application is installed)

6º If you want to send notifications while the **application is closed** some ROMs dont allow this except facebook, whatsapp(golden apps) etc you must go to your battery optimization and put your app in the **protected application**(this changes from brand to brand). The ideal approach is to give the user an initial popup to help him do this.

This is what I learned and it works for me. Any question post above, I will try to research more about this and update while I get more information.